# jQuery fancybox z-index issue in safari

Tags: jquery, css, safari, fancybox, z-index

I am using jQuery fancybox for display YouTube video but getting border issue in Safari bowser. In other browser I am getting proper display.

[image]

My Fiddle: [Fiddle](http://goo.gl/UkK0L8)

Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a `z-index` issue.

As a rule of thumb, add `wmode` to your videos or flash objects and you will save yourself from odd behaviors.

In the case of the embedded `iframe`, add `wmode` to the linked video as a trial parameter within the `src` attribute like :

```
<iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/Qh5m-KTR36U?wmode=opaque" width="420" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

In the case of the video that opens in fancybox, add it as a trial parameter within the `href` (otherwise fancybox close button will be placed behind the video) like :

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/L9szn1QQfas?autoplay=1&wmode=opaque"class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" >...</a>
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6KhQL/)**

Comment: Hey man you saved my life. Thank you so much for your help :) Thumbs up for you :)